# Adjusting the logistic regression for continuous covariates using restricted cubic splines

Tags: regression, logistic, splines

I am trying to understand how to fit and interpret the logistic regression that is adjusted to a covariate using restricted cubic splines.
Groenwold at al. in 2013 have shown that RCS is among the best for adjustment for covariates.

As an example I would use lung cancer data from "survival" package.
The code is:

```
library(survival)
library(Hmisc)
library(rms)
data("lung")
# transforming the STATUS column to be 0 (censored) or 1 (dead)
lung$status<- lung$status-1
```

Fitting the logistic regression using RCS with 5 knots give me this:

```
    rfit <- lrm(status ~ ph.karno+meal.cal+rcs(age,5), data=lung)
    rfit[[5]]
    Intercept      ph.karno      meal.cal           age          age'         age''        age''' 
-6.9646658125 -0.0235944406  0.0004315636  0.1906079292 -0.5644936253  3.3031119981 -5.2273167735
```

First of all I don't understand what is the interpretation of 4 new versions of age?! It's absolutely not clear to me from the "rms" package description.

Next I decided to use rcspline.eval function from "Hmisc" package for age with 5 knots.

```
x <- rcspline.eval (lung$age, nk=5, inclx =T )
matplot(x[,1], x, type="p", lty=1, pch=19, xlab="Age", ylab="")
```

[image: Different versions of Age]

And now I have 3 new versions of the transformed age.

I understand the Restricted Cubic Splines formula but don't understand the interpretation of the output of either of these function. Why do they have 4 and 3 versions of age?

Comment: As an aside make sure that you should not be doing a 'time to event' analysis (survival analysis).  Your 2nd approach just showed the basis functions.  Stick with `rcs` and plot the fitted shape using a partial effects plot.  You need to study my RMS course notes in detail before proceeding: http://www.fharrell.com/p/blog-page.html ; don't try to interpret coefficients of individual spline terms.

Comment: Dear Frank, thanks for your response! I've read the Restricted Cubic Splines section from the Regression Modelling Strategies course - that's where I found how to use the rcs and rcsspline.eval. Just to clarify: am I right that in my example I get 4 coeficients for age because the Intercept in already given and these coefficients are b1, b2, b3, b4 in the cubic spline equaion? And the 3 new figures on my plot are these newly made X2, X3 and X4 with the original as X1?

Comment: I am learning this too, I used latex(rfit) to check the fitted function and there are five coefficients for the cubic terms, I also confused.

Comment: `latex()` represents cubic splines in simplest forms but adding 2 redundant parameters.  For your purpose a rcs with k knots needs k-2 nonlinear terms plus the original linear term.  This is all akin to fitting a quadratic in x which means using 2 columns x x^2.  Right about the figure with 4 curves.  But you want a single fitted curve for the main analysis.

Comment: Correct link is https://hbiostat.org/rms